# Getting Fatal Error on Ubuntu 16.04: Unable to create lock file

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I found on my server (ubuntu 16.04) that there is almost no free space and it requires to be cleaned up. I started to find out which directory or path has taken more space and I can clean them up. After finishing it up, an issue was occurred  and I got error while running some console command. For example when I run **php -v** I get this error:

```
(19903): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
```

I cannot also run **apt-get update**.

How can I recover the server at this point?

Comment: Mayve too many files open? Since your not wrote if its a VM or physical Server you may try https://www.google.com/amp/s/anandarajpandey.com/2016/02/18/solved-fatal-error-unable-to-create-lock-file-bad-file-descriptor-9/amp/ However you should really post more Information about your issue

Comment: Which directories did you clean up?

Comment: I found the problem. the directory /tmp was removed. I just recreated the directory.